# Dash python: server-side vs client-side callback

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am experimenting with front-end work and web-based apps and **I am wondering if the following the best approach to avoid performance issues.**
Part of this doubt comes from not knowing exactly if it would be better in this case to have a server-side or client-side callback (I haven't fully grasped when it is recommended to implement each).

Here are the details:
I have a computationally intense process that runs using `MyClass.myFunction()`.
This involves a series of sub-functions that fetch data from a database, do calculations/manipulations and then load the data up on screen.

Currently I have:

1. A button that fires the fetch and data manipulation.
2. A container to store the retrieved data when the button is clicked.
3. A dash.DataTable to visualize that refreshes when the button is
   clicked and that visualizes the output of MyClass.myFunction().

Users will then be able to modify the displayed data and send the results to a database (have not implemented the button yet).

Extra info: `MyClass.myFunction()` requires some input (`input_parameters`) this is a yaml configuration file (stored as dictionary) containing dates, strings and doubles, to allow the function to retrieve the appropriate values.
They are displayed in a different page to allow users to modify them and then preserved for the session.

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, dash_table, Input, Output, State, callback, ctx
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import pandas as pd
from mymodule import SomeClass

dash.register_page(__name__, name="My Page")

MyClass= SomeClass()

number_clicks_fetch = 0

layout = html.Div(
children=[
    html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(children='My title'),
        dash_table.DataTable(
            # data= #this will be populated via callback
            # columns= #this will be populated via callback
            persistence=True,
            persisted_props =['columns.name', 'data'],
            persistence_type='session',
            virtualization=True,

            id='data_table'
        )
    ], style={'width': '100%,'}),
    #store fetched data for the remainder of the session
    dcc.Store(id='data_storage', storage_type='session'),
    html.Button('Fetch data', id='fetch-data-button', n_clicks=number_clicks_fetch)   
])

# if button clicked, populate table
@callback(Output('data_storage', 'data'),
             Input('fetch-data-button', 'n_clicks'),
             Input('input_parameters', 'data'),
             )
def fetch_data(clicks, input_parameters):
    global MyClass
    if clicks == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        mydata = MyClass.myFunction(input_parameters)
        return mydata.to_dict('records')
    

    # if storage is updated, update table
@callback([Output('data_table','data'), 
            Output('data_table','columns')],
            Input('fetch-data-button', 'n_clicks'),
            State('data_storage', 'data'))
def refresh_table(n_clicks, data):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        columns = [{'id': c, 'name': c, "deletable": False, "selectable": True} for c in data[0].keys()],
        # print(data)
    return [data, columns]
```

Comment: The first few lines about [clientside callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) should answer the question quite nicely.

Comment: @EricLavault except it doesn't. If I understand correctly how front-end works: The data is on a database. The app is running on a server. The client browser fires the callback (which could be on a different network than server and database). With a standard callback the fetching and computation is done on the server and the result then sent to the browser. Is it the additional transfer from DB to server that makes it inefficient compared to a client-side callback? Which computational resources are then used if the callback is on client-side?

Comment: Client-side callbacks are just javascript callbacks, they run in the browser and use those resources of the client machine. "_The data is on a database_", not necessarily, which data for which app ? Some data could be submitted by the user, and not all data need to persist on the backend (if at all), one could store some in the browser session or localStorage ([dcc.Store](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store)). More importantly, not all data need to be sent back and forth between server and client, and callbacks don't have to run on the backend for every single user interaction.

Comment: @EricLavault sorry, I was unclear. In my case I have data stored on DB, which together with the server live on the same network. So I understand that avoiding the transfer (particularly if it happens multiple times) between client and server is the way to optimize here.